# Object required error in Set =

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build some code that inserts a name and email address in to the next open row from the next row in the loop. I am getting an error in Set = Number of Emails line and I am not sure why.

```
Sub Email_Copy()
    Dim Data As Worksheet
        Set Data = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Dim Email_Database As Worksheet
        Set Email_Database = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Email_Database")
    Dim Number_Of_Emails As Integer
        Set Number_Of_Emails = Data.Range("L6002")
    Dim Total_Emails As Long
        Set Total_Emails = Email_Database.Range("D2")
    Dim X As Long

    For X = 1 To Number_Of_Emails
     Set Email_Database.Range("B3").Offset(Total_Emails, 0) = Data.Range("D3").Offset(Number_Of_Emails, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Number_Of_Emails As Integer` then you try to set a `range` to it. Edit: you want `Number_Of_Emails = Data.Range("L6002").value`

Comment: @findwindow I have tried that as well and I get the same error. It works thought when I dim as range. Good call.

Comment: @findwindow If you post as an answer I will gladly accept it so the question gets answered.

Comment: just to help with more clarity, `Set` is only required with Object Type variables (hence the error). A `Range` variable is an Object Type. An Integer, being a number, is not an object type. (String is not on object either. Worksheet is an Object Type). So it's `Set rng = Range("A1")` when `Dim rng as Range` and `iRng = Range("A1").Value` when `Dim iRng as Integer`.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared  `Number_Of_Emails As Integer` but then tried to `set` it to a `range` so it's a type mismatch. You can simply do

```
Number_Of_Emails = Data.Range("L6002").value
```

Edit: to plagarize Scott Holtzman's comment verbatim

> Set is only required with Object Type variables (hence the error). A
>   Range variable is an Object Type. An Integer, being a number, is not
>   an object type. (String is not on object either). Worksheet is an
>   Object Type.